# How to force browser to expire cache of a specific page?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching, meta-tags

I am confused with caching. I know that there are different types of caching as follows, but the question is how to have it for separate dynamic pages.

```
Public - may be cached in public shared caches (proxies and users)
Private - may only be cached in private cache (users only)
no-Cache - may not be cached
no-Store - may be cached but not archived
```

Lets say I have specified 'public cache' and have following two addresses and I need to just remove the cache for user 908. Should I pass the meta as a new attribute of the model? whats the best approach?

```
www.example.com/users?id=100
www.example.com/users?id=908
```

**Expire cache**

```
if(user.cacheExpire){
    model.addAttribute("meta","<meta name="expires" content=" + user.cacheDate + "> ";
}
model.addAttribute("user",user);
return "UserPage";
```

does this force user's browser to remove the cache for **user with 908 id** only? Is that the best approach?